# Failed to execute /sbin/sulogin: Permission Denied

Tags: server, grub2

I think somehow I messed up with my `sudoers`.

When I power-on my machine I will get:

```
"Failed to execute /sbin/sulogin: Permission Denied"
```

Even if I log in in recovery mode I will get the same message. I'm on Ubuntu Server 18.04. How can I boot with root user?

Comment: You haven't given your OS/release, but an error in the sudoers file is treated as the *end-of-file* marker, thus why it should be edited via `visudo` (which prevents exit if errors are detected in the file; visudo will use whatever editor you have setup as default, which need not be `vi`)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu Server 18.04.3 LTS. I haven't edited sudoers. In fact I've swtiched to another user that isn't super user and shut down the machine (on the host). When I turn it back on the message above is displayed.

Comment: What are the ownership and permissions? `/bin/ls -ld /sbin /sbin/sulogin`. What have you done to your system lately?

Comment: @AntonioAraujo The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the [edit] button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: @waltinator do you mean to execute this command in grub? I don't have access to any shell. I created a user, switched to this user, tried to switch back to root and wasn't able (probably a Path problem). So I turned down the machine and power it back up. Then I got this problem.

Comment: Your further information lacks details, and you were thrashing the problem environment. Probably not a Path problem (did you mean `$PATH`?

Comment: Boot from a live USB, mount your disk, copy `/etc/sudoers` from the live USB to your disk.

Comment: Yes, I did mean $PATH. But now I think I will blow everything up and start with a new installation. Thanks for your help anyway.